# Datepicker calendar doesn't display in modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, datepicker

I am fairly new to coding and am having trouble getting the bootstrap-datepicker (https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails) to open correctly. While the modal works, the datepicker does not - I'd appreciate if someone could help point me in the right direction.

I'm not sure whether the problem is caused by:
A) Javascript in the wrong place? I have a couple of `<script>` under `<head>` and the datepicker script right before the `</body>` tag.
B) Missing some file in assets/javascripts? I've added bootstrap.js and bootstrap-datepicker.js here already.
C) Something else?

Here's the HTML in `application.html.erb`:

```
<head>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
        <a id="link" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Get started now</a>
        <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="well">
                <input type="text" data-behaviour='datepicker' >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker({
                "format": "yyyy-mm-dd",
                "weekStart": 1,
                "autoclose": true
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem. The issue was that I was loading the javascript files too many times:
A) installing the gems and using `//= require` in the `application.js` file
B) also placing the files in the assets/javascripts folder (these files were loaded a second time through `//= require_tree .` in the `application.js` file)
C) also linking to the files through `<script>` tags in the HTML

Fixed the issue by doing A) only. Hope this helps someone else!